# Starting a sentence with 'Having' or 'When provided with'

Tags: word-choice, grammar, grammaticality

I first thought using **having** to state my argument as follows:

> Having an opinion on the likely participation in X, an instructor can...

Then, I thought about replacing it with:

> When provided with an estimation of likely participation in X, an instructor can...

I wonder if these two sentences actually carry a different meaning, and if not, which would be more proper choice?

Comment: Your first sentence uses the participle clause improperly in my view. It does not really communicate the conditional sense, but conveys the impression that instructors by definition have an opinion on the likely participation in X. 'An instructor who has ...' works, as does your second suggestion.

Comment: Side note: I would write "the likelihood of participation in X" rather than "likely participation". Much clearer that way.

Comment: I've voted to close.  I don't think this question has enough context to sort out some strange things in the two sentences, let alone provide guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the sentences are different in structure and meaning. The first one is begun with the -ing participle (present participle) and the second one with the past participle. Present participles have an active meaning, whereas Past participles most often have a passive meaning.

The first sentence means: An instructor can...as he has an opinion....

The second sentence means: An instructor can...when he is provided with...

Comment: Thanks! I will use `when provided with` !